# Does Core Data not support custom types? What should I use to store currency?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am using https://github.com/peek-travel/swift-currency, and have a model of identifiable where one of the fields is "var price:USD" (price variable of type USD (from the library). I noticed if I want to use coredata, there is no 'USD' type for me to use. Is there a way I could use this type with core data? Or is it better practice to use a different (already out of the box) type for storing currency (e.g. $5.08 data in swiftui/swift?

Regardless of what that type is, what I've been doing when doing transformation on that type (say I need to add $5 to the value of 'price') I usually do: USD(5.08) + USD(5). So it seems like it might be bothersome to have to continuously take the value out of coredata and put it in a USD(..) before performing any transformation, then converting it back to whatever type is supported for CoreData. Though if it is best practice, I am fine with it.

Comment: You can use a [`Transformable type`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/handling_different_data_types_in_core_data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can support custom types. You need a `class` that conforms to `NSSecureCoding` and `NSObject`

Also, you need a Transformer that conforms to `NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer`

Then in CoreData you set the attribute `type` to `Transformable` and the `Transformer` = `YourClassTransformer` and the `Custom Class` = `YourClass`

```
@objc(USD)
public class USD: NSObject {
    var value: Double
    
    public enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case value
    }
    public init(value: Double) {
        self.value = value
    }
    public required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        value = coder.decodeObject(forKey: CodingKeys.value.rawValue) as! Double
    }
    
    public override var description: String{
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .currency
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
        return formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: value))! 
    }
}
extension USD: NSSecureCoding{
    public static var supportsSecureCoding: Bool{
        return true
    }
    public func encode(with coder: NSCoder) {
        coder.encode(value, forKey: CodingKeys.value.rawValue)
    }
}
@objc(USDTransformer)
public final class USDTransformer: NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer {
    public static let name = NSValueTransformerName(rawValue: String(describing: USDTransformer.self))
    public override static var allowedTopLevelClasses: [AnyClass] {
        return [USD.self]
    }
    //Register before CoreData setup starts
    public static func register() {
        
        let transformer = USDTransformer()
        ValueTransformer.setValueTransformer(transformer, forName: name)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Out of sheer curiosity, is this... ideal though? Or given my case since I am trying to deal with money, that I should just stick with one of the types out of the box?

Comment: It is a lot of work for a `Double var` and a `description` that shows $. I am actually putting together the code just for "fun" if you give me a bit I will post it.

Comment: Thanks, so even though it is clearly possible... probably better to stick with the double for coredata price type? Thank you for the code, this really helps make how this can be done clearly.

Comment: Probably, it is hard for me to imagine a scenario were the persistence work would be worth it. It would have to be a money heavy app that would include other properties like converters, equations to see future value, etc.