# Update Core Data value, SwiftUI

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I have a list of object:

```
@FetchRequest(entity: ObjectDetail.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var myObject: FetchedResults<ObjectDetail>
```

My ObjectDetail is an Entity in my .xcdatamodel with a structure like this:

```
listOfObject: Transformable (List of custom object)
objectId: UUID
objectName: String
objectDescription: String
```

ListOfObject:

```
public class ListOfObject: NSObject, NSCoding, ObservableObject {
...
}
```

I'm trying to update an element inside my listOfObject.

Here are 3 approaches I tried so far:

1. First approach:

   ```
   mangedObjectContext.performAndWait {
       self.elementFromListOfObject.objectWillChange.send()
       elementFromListOfObject.weight = 0
       try? mangedObjectContext.save()
   }
   ```
2. Second approach:

   ```
   if let selectedObject = self. myObject.first(where: {$0.objectName == self.currentSelectedObjectName}) {
       if let selectedElementFromListOfObject = selectedObject.myList?.myListOfObject.first(where: {$0 == self.currentSelectedObject }) {
           selectedElementFromListOfObject.weight = 0
           self.excercise.objectWillChange.send()
           saveContext()
       }
   }
   ```
3. Third approach

   ```
   do {
       let request = NSBatchUpdateRequest(entity: ObjectDetail.entity())
       request.resultType = .updatedObjectIDsResultType
       request.propertiesToUpdate = ["weight": 0]

       let result = try mangedObjectContext.execute(request) as? NSBatchUpdateResult
       let objectIDArray = result?.result as? [NSManagedObjectID]
       let changes = [NSUpdatedObjectsKey: objectIDArray]
       NSManagedObjectContext.mergeChanges(fromRemoteContextSave: changes as [AnyHashable : Any], into: [mangedObjectContext])
   } catch {
       let nsError = error as NSError
       fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
   }
   ```

The third one crashed because it says request.propertiesToUpdate is null, the other approaches save the value, but when I restart the app its the default one.

- - 

What is the best approach to update a value in Core Data in SwiftUI?

Comment: I would suggest creating a new entity in Core Data for ListOfObject and using a relationship instead of a transformable object

Comment: A transformable is a world of pain, with no gain in this instance. @JoakimDanielson is absolutely correct. Model it as a relationship, especially since the `Entity` already exists.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69153791/how-to-delete-and-update-structure-type-array-in-core-data-ios-swift/69335920#69335920