# Store Leaderboard Scores in CoreData?

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, swiftui, cloudkit

I am trying to store a leaderboard in CoreData(with eventual CloudKit functionality) on my app and was confused about how to best do so.

The user will be able to create and save multiple leaderboards. Each leaderboard will have a creation date, name, ID, as well as all the scores for that leaderboard. In the core data model (below), I added all those as attributes to the leaderboard entity and for the score attribute, I left it as undefined. I was thinking of making it an array of my `score` struct. However, when I try to do, `newLearboard.scores = [Score]()` in my `Persistence.swift` file I am told I need to add the score `as NSObject`. Is this the correct way to do this or will this create unintended consequences when I go to add/display the leaderboard of scores?

Score is a struct with a few fields such as name and value etc.

I may also convert the Score array to an OrderedSet from the swift collections package eventually. Will this create other issues?

[image]

Comment: No it is not, create a new entity Score and then a one-to-many relationship between Leaderboard and Score

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to delete and update structure type array in core data iOS swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69153791/how-to-delete-and-update-structure-type-array-in-core-data-ios-swift)

Comment: You can it is easy to do as you will see in the post I tagged above but you run the possibility of losing the whole thing if there is an error. It is all saved onto one variable as a string. Creating an entity that is related to leaderboard is the safer way.

Answer (score 0):

Core Data doesn't know how to store Swift structs. Xcode's trying to help but not really succeeding. Using `as NSObject` won't do what you want because a struct can't be typecast to an `NSObject`.

The Core Data way would be to add a second entity to the model called `Score` and then add a Core Data to-many relationship from `Leaderboard` to `Score`. Then each `Score` would be an `NSManagedObject`, which is a subclass of `NSObject`.

It's also possible to put anything in Core Data if you can convert it to a an instance `Data` first. If you used `JSONEncoder` you could convert your score array to `Data` and use a `Data` attribute. You would have to write code to encode every time you update scores, and decode every time you read scores. If you decide to do this, keep in mind that although `JSONEncoder` uses `Codable`, `Codable` is not useful with Core Data (it can use `NSCoding` but that's not the same thing).

Comment: Converting to Data gives the secure coding warning message it has to be converted to string or something like that.

Comment: That doesn't match my experience. What I'm describing doesn't involve `NSCoding` at all, so messages it would print about secure coding don't happen.

Comment: Maybe we are talking about different tactics. What I am referring to is the style used on the question I linked above. That secure coding message using data comes up more and more using transformable. The exact error message is in the comments.

Comment: I was specifically avoiding transformable attributes-- which `JSONEncoder` wouldn't work with, anyway.