# How to implement Core Data Transformable type for [[Int?]] and [[String?]]

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

For my question I have prepared [a simple SwiftUI project](https://github.com/afarber/ios-questions/tree/master/TransApp/TransApp) at GitHub.

A backend sends the following JSON data to my app, representing a game with a 15 x 15 letters:

```
{
    "gid":266,
    "letters":[
        [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
        [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
        [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
        [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
        [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
        [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
        [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,"H", null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
        [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,"U", null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
        [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,"E", null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
        [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
        [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
        [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
        [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
        [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
        [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]
    ],
    "values":[
        [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
        [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
        [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
        [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
        [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
        [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
        [null,null,null,null,null,null,null, 4,  null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
        [null,null,null,null,null,null,null, 1,  null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
        [null,null,null,null,null,null,null, 1,  null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
        [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
        [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
        [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
        [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
        [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],
        [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]
    ],
    "tiles":[
        {"col": 8, "row": 7, "value": 1, "letter": "E"},
        {"col": 7, "row": 7, "value": 1, "letter": "U"},
        {"col": 6, "row": 7, "value": 4, "letter": "H"}
    ]
}
```

As you can see the `letters` and `values` are 2-dimensional arrays of `String?` and `Int?` and that is how I have defined them in the [GameModel.swift](https://github.com/afarber/ios-questions/tree/master/TransApp/TransApp) which I use for JSON parsing:

```
struct GameModel: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int32 { gid }
    let gid: Int32
    let letters: [[String?]]
    let values: [[Int32?]]
    let tiles: [TileModel]? // the previous move as an array

    // create a new Core Data entity and copy the properties
    func toEntity(viewContext: NSManagedObjectContext) -> GameEntity {
        let gameEntity = GameEntity(context: viewContext)
        gameEntity.gid = self.gid
        gameEntity.letters = self.letters
        gameEntity.values = self.values
        gameEntity.tiles = self.tiles
        return gameEntity
    }
}

struct TileModel: Codable {
    let col: Int
    let row: Int
    let value: Int
    let letter: String
}
```

I am trying to parse them by using the `Transformable` Core Data type and thus I have added these 3 lines to the [Persistence.swift](https://github.com/afarber/ios-questions/tree/master/TransApp/TransApp)

```
let container: NSPersistentContainer

init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
    ValueTransformer.setValueTransformer(ValuesToDataTransformer(), forName: .valuesToDataTransformer)
    ValueTransformer.setValueTransformer(LettersToDataTransformer(), forName: .lettersToDataTransformer)
    ValueTransformer.setValueTransformer(TilesToDataTransformer(), forName: .tilesToDataTransformer)

    container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "TransApp")
```

Also I have added the 3 files:

- [LettersToDataTransformer.swift](https://github.com/afarber/ios-questions/tree/master/TransApp/TransApp)
- [ValuesToDataTransformer.swift](https://github.com/afarber/ios-questions/tree/master/TransApp/TransApp)
- [TilesToDataTransformer.swift](https://github.com/afarber/ios-questions/tree/master/TransApp/TransApp)

My problem is that my custom `ValueTransformer` sub classes do not compile.

The error is:

> Static method 'unarchivedObject(ofClass:from:)' requires that '[[Int32?]]' conform to 'NSCoding'

and similar for the 2 others.

Comment: Regarding the “has no member” errors, you need to create a NSValueTransformerName instance for each transformer. See the example on [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/valuetransformer) documentation page

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69153791/how-to-delete-and-update-structure-type-array-in-core-data-ios-swift/69335920#69335920

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a completely different approach avoiding `Transformable`. It saves only the `TileModel` array as JSON string and uses computed properties to create the grids and to convert the custom type to and from JSON.

Actually you don't need to decode the grids at all.

- In the entity declare `tiles` as `String`

  ```
  @NSManaged public var tiles: String?
  ```
- Add a computed property to convert an array of `TileModel` to JSON

  ```
  var tileArray: [TileModel]? {
      get {
          guard let data = tiles?.data(using: .utf8) else { return nil }
          return try? JSONDecoder().decode([TileModel].self, from: data)
      }
      set {
          guard let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(newValue) else { tiles = nil; return }
          tiles = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
      }
  }
  ```
- And the computed properties to create the grids, there is no reason to save them in the entity

  ```
  var values : [[Int?]] {
        var grid : [[Int?]] = [
            [nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil],
            [nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil],
            [nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil],
            [nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil],
            [nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil],
            [nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil],
            [nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil],
            [nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil],
            [nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil],
            [nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil],
            [nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil],
            [nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil],
            [nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil],
            [nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil],
            [nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil]]
        tileArray?.forEach{ grid[$0.col][$0.row] = $0.value }
        return grid
    }

  var letters : [[String?]] {
        var grid : [[String?]] = [
            [nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil],
            [nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil],
            [nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil],
            [nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil],
            [nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil],
            [nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil],
            [nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil],
            [nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil],
            [nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil],
            [nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil],
            [nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil],
            [nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil],
            [nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil],
            [nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil],
            [nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil]]
        tileArray?.forEach{ grid[$0.col][$0.row] = $0.letter }
        return grid
    }
  ```

Comment: Ah I see that I have used an unlucky example data and you have thought that tiles data replicates letters/values data. While in my [real game](https://wordsbyfarber.com/en/android) the tiles only holds the *last* move and letters/values holds *all* letter tiles at the game board... Still thank you for replying, upvoted. By "Add a computed property" do you mean to select "Create NSManaged Subclass..." in Xcode and put the code into the generated class?

Comment: Yes, or write an extension of the class.

Comment: Thank you, I have added [GameEntity+Extensions.swift](https://github.com/afarber/ios-questions/tree/master/TransApp/TransApp) and it seems to work.