# Swift: Insert codable object into Core Data

Tags: swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext, xcode14

I'm getting a response from an API and decoding the response like this:

```
struct MyStuff: Codable {
    let name: String
    let quantity: Int
    let location: String
}
```

And I have instance an Entity to map `MyStuff`:

```
@objc(Stuff)
public class Stuff: NSManagedObject {
}

extension Stuff {
    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Stuff> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Stuff>(entityName: "Stuff")
    }
    @NSManaged public var name: String?
    @NSManaged public var quantity: Int64
    @NSManaged public var location: String?
}
```

My question is, when I have the response of type MyStuff there is a way to loop thru the keys and map the values to core data?

for example:

```
let myStuff = MyStuff(name: "table", quantity: 1, location: "kitchen")

let myStuff = MyStuff(name: "table", quantity: 1, location: "kitchen")
        for chidren in Mirror(reflecting: myStuff).children {
            print(chidren.label)
            print(chidren.value)
            /*
             insert values to core data
             */
        }
```

I'll really appreciate your help

Comment: Maybe you could use KVC but why, you get much better and cleaner code if you manually map the properties even though that would require a bit more work. And then you also might have the option to make your entity `Stuff` conform to `Codable` and skip `MyStuff` altogether.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Can you post an example?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete and update structure type array in Core Data iOS Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69153791/how-to-delete-and-update-structure-type-array-in-core-data-ios-swift)

Comment: https://www.donnywals.com/using-codable-with-core-data-and-nsmanagedobject/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A smart solution is to adopt `Decodable` in `Stuff`

Write an extension of `CodingUserInfoKey` and `JSONDecoder`

```
extension CodingUserInfoKey {
    static let context = CodingUserInfoKey(rawValue: "context")!
}

extension JSONDecoder {
    convenience init(context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        self.init()
        self.userInfo[.context] = context
    }
}
```

In `Stuff` adopt `Decodable` and implement `init(from:)`, it must be implemented in the class, not in the extension

```
@objc(Stuff)
public class Stuff: NSManagedObject, Decodable {

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case name, quantity, location }
    
    public required convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        guard let context = decoder.userInfo[.context] as? NSManagedObjectContext else { fatalError("Error: context doesn't exist!") }
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Stuff", in: context)!
        self.init(entity: entity, insertInto: context)
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        name = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .name)
        quantity = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int64.self, forKey: .quantity) ?? 0
        location = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .location)
    }
}
```

To decode the JSON you have to initialize the decoder with the convenience initializer

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder(context: context)
```

where `context` is the current `NSManagedObjectContext` instance.

Now you can create `Stuff` instances directly from the JSON.

Comment: where does `self.userInfo` is coming from?

Comment: It belongs to `JSONDecoder` to be able to pass custom data.

Comment: How do you save the data in your example?

Comment: Save the context.

Comment: I'm decoding `let response = try decoder.decode(MyStuff.self, from: data)` and `let stuff = Stuff(from: response)` but I'm getting this error `Argument type 'MyStuff' does not conform to expected type 'Decoder'`. Do you know why ?

Comment: No, the goal is to drop `MyStuff` completely and decode `Stuff.self`

Answer (score 0):

You can store entire object as JSONString if you don't support query for each field.
If you need query for some field then keep that field in entity object.

```
struct MyStuff: Codable {
    let name: String
    let quantity: Int
    let location: String
}
 
extension Encodable {
    func toString() -> String? {
        if let config = try? JSONEncoder().encode(self) {
            return String(data: config, encoding: .utf8)
        }
        return .none
    }
}
 
extension Decodable {
    static func map(JSONString: String) -> Self? {
        try? JSONDecoder().decode(Self.self, from: JSONString.data(using: .utf8) ?? .init())
    }
}
 
 
@objc(Stuff)
public class Stuff: NSManagedObject {
}
 
// Entity with single field (no field base query support)
extension Stuff {
    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Stuff> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Stuff>(entityName: "Stuff")
    }
    @NSManaged public var myStuffRawJSON: String?
 
    func mapToMyStuff() -> MyStuff? {
        MyStuff.map(JSONString: myStuffRawJSON ?? "")
    }
}
```

How to use:

```
let myStuff = MyStuff(name: "table", quantity: 1, location: "kitchen")

let entity: Stuff //Create entity
entity.myStuffRawJSON = myStuff.toString()
// save your entity
```

Comment: question. How to execute this code?

Comment: Updated please check

Comment: does `myStuffRawJSON ` contains all the keys from `MyStuff ` ?

Comment: @user2924482 yes it contain all keys and values. Also yo can retrieve back `Stuff. mapToMyStuff ()`

Comment: In future if you add new property then you don't needs to change any thing at database level